# Tensorflow minibatch training

Tags: tensorflow

How can I train a network in TensorFlow using minibatches of data?
In the Deep-MNIST tutorial, they use:

```
for i in range(1000):
   batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
   train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

My question is - are `x` and `y_` variables with dimensions suitable to a single example, and `batch[0]`,`batch[1]` are lists of such inputs and outputs? in this case, will TensorFlow automatically add the gradients for each training example in these lists? or should I create my model so that `x` and `y_` get an entire minibatch?

My problem is that when I try to feed it a list for each placeholder, it tries to input the entire list for the placeholder, and I therefore get a size mismatch: `Cannot feed value of shape (n, m) for Tensor u'ts:0', which has shape '(m,)'`, where `n` is the minibatch size and `m` is the individual input size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the MNIST tutorial `x` and `y_`are placeholders with a defined shape:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
```

The `shape=[None, 784]` means that this placeholder have 2 dimension.

So, to answer your first question:

> are x and y_ variables with dimensions suitable to a single example

The first dimension can contain an undefined number of elements (so, 1, 2, ... 50 ...) and the second dimension can contain exaclly 784 = 28*28 elements (that are the features of a single MNIST image).

If you feed the graph with a python list with shape [1, 784] or [50, 784] is totally the same for tensorflow, it can handle it without any problem.

> batch[0],batch[1] are lists of such inputs and outputs?
>   in the tutorial they define batch calling `batch = datasets.train.next_batch(50)`.
>   Thus:

- batch[0] is a list with shape [50, 784]
- batch[1] is a list with shape [50, 10]

> will TensorFlow automatically add the gradients for each training example in these lists? or should I create my model so that x and y_ get an entire minibatch?

Tensorflow handles this for you.

The error you're reporting `Cannot feed value of shape (n, m) for Tensor u'ts:0', which has shape '(m,)'`
is a shape mismatch error.

You're not reshaping the inputs to have the same shape of the placeholder.

Comment: "Tensorflow handles this for you." - but my cost function will still need to sum over an unknown number of samples (that will be set when applying run), right? It's not that I write a cost function for a single sample and it extends it somehow.

Comment: Yes, it's right. The tf.reduce* function will help you to sum/average over the unknown number of sample