# Extract Bottleneck Features in Batch Mode

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the `Inception Model` to extract the features for `Transfer Learning` in `Tensorflow`. Major issue is that it only extract feature for one image at a time. How can I use it for `Batch Mode` to make it fast?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by extracting features? Do you replace the top layers and train the new model on a new dataset? Do you want to do training using batches? If so, this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157794/tensorflow-minibatch-training.

Comment: I am fetching features of second to last layer. But right now its only one image at a time. How can I do it for batch mode?

Comment: It is a very common practice to make the first dimension of all tensors in a model to be the batch dimension. Inception model (at least if you mean this one https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v4.py) is no exception. If you pass multiple inputs in a batch, you will get features for all of them.